# Line smoothness/waviness

Tags: smoothing, curves

I am working on a project which requires me to watch video of athletes and measure the straightness/smoothness/waviness, whatever term is acceptable, of their spine. Dividing the spine into segments may also be acceptable if it provides the best results.

Right now I can plot x and y points on still images. Not sure what my next step should be. Simple measures like curvature and radius if I made little circles don't work because the subject may be near or far in the image, skewing the results. I would like the output to be some sort of ratio.

Comment: Are these animated or taken from a still position? Are you measuring torsion?

Comment: Moving camera video. I just pause it at appropriate times and take a screenshot. I've been using some image analysis software but it only gets me so far without knowing the right stat to use that will get rid of the noise due to distance of the subject.

Comment: I have not thought of measuring torsion. But I mean the capabilities are limited in terms of measuring anything 3d. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes. Just making sure you are only interested in modeling a straight line.